# Appear text when the bar in the top

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

how can I appear a text when the the navbar is in the top and when I scroll down the text appear in the navbar 
i want the text P_DECO in the h1 appear on scroll down and be hide when the bar is on the top of the website

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
   <div class="container">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <h1 class="h">P-DECO</h1>
    </div>
    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li>
                <a href="index.html">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="aboutus.html">About Us</a>
            </li>
               <li>
                <a href="services.html">Services</a>
            </li>
               <li>
                <a href="factory.html">Factory</a>
            </li>
               <li>
                <a href="projects.html">Projects</a>
            </li>
               <li>
                <a href="client.html">Clients</a>
            </li>
               <li>
                <a href="video.html">Video</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="contactus.html">Contact Us</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
</div>
<!-- /.container -->
```

Comment: can you post your css?

Comment: i really dont see how this thing goes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use jQuery :

```
 $(window).on("scroll", function() {
    var h_title = $(".h");
        var scrollPos = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (scrollPos < 100) {
            h_title.fadeIn();
        } else {
            h_title.fadeOut();
        }
    });
```

`100` has to be adapted for your needs.

**EDIT**

You'd better set an `id` for the `<h1 class="h">P-DECO</h1>`.
Then the second line should look like this :

```
var h_title = $("#YOUR_ID");
```

Comment: it work but when the site is loading for the first time the text appear than when i scroll and go back to the top the code work correctly